# Why is the polymer element <paper-button> not rendering

Tags: dart, dart-polymer

why is the `<paper-button>` not rendering? Everything else works and the button with `id=button1` is rendered. 
I have tried to use a different path:

```
<link rel="import" href="../../packages/paper_elements/paper_button.html">
```

but it still does not work. I'm using dart 1.91 polymer  polymer:0.16.0+7 paper_elements :0.6.2+3

```dart
//***************INDEX.HTML FILE 
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="styles/main.css">
<link rel="import" href="packages/polymer/polymer.html">
<link rel="import" href="packages/paper_elements/paper_button.html">
<script src="packages/browser/dart.js"></script>
<script type="application/dart" src="main.dart"></script>

<title>Test my polymetr test 152</title>
</head>

<body unresolved>
  <h1 id="output">the output div</h1>
  <label id="hello">hello vr y31</label>
  <button id="button1">Enter button</button>
  <paper-button></paper-button>
</body>
</html>
```

```dart
//***************MAIN.DART FILE 
// Copyright (c) 2015, <your name>. All rights reserved. Use of this source code
// is governed by a BSD-style license that can be found in the LICENSE file.

import 'dart:html';
import "dart:async";
import 'package:polymer/polymer.dart';

void main() {
   void realMain() {
    Element abc=querySelector("#output");
    abc.text="Up and running";
  };

  initPolymer().then((zone) => zone.run(realMain));
  Element button1=querySelector("#button1");
  button1.onClick.listen(buttonClick);
}

void buttonClick(Event e){
  (e.target as ButtonElement).text='Clicked button';
}
```

```yml
//***************PUPSPEC.YAML file
name: Atests
version: 0.0.1
description: An absolute bare-bones web app.
environment:
  sdk: '>=1.0.0 <2.0.0'
dependencies:
  browser: any
  paper_elements: 0.6.2+3
  polymer: '>=0.16.0+7 <0.17.0'
transformers:
- polymer:
    entry_points: web/index.html
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you add some text ((`<paper-button>xxx</paper-button>`) you'll see the button is there, it is just not visible. Also when you investigate the DOM in Chrome dev tools you'll see the `<paper-button>` element is there and also has a shadow DOM (if you activate in dev-tools settings to show the shadow DOM) which indicates the element was properly initialized.
Even without adding text you can click the button (just right of the [Enter button] and you'll see the ripple effect.

Comment: Thank you very much. I am just starting with dart and I did not Know that Dev tools existed. this is great!